# Add multiple children entities to the root aggreate or call multiple respositories

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern, aggregateroot

I have an entity A which has three children entities X, Y and Z.

I have also a generic repository one of those floating around the web...

In my Service method AXYZ()

I do multiple repositories calls: (pseudo code)

```
repoA.Update(objectA);
repoY.Delete(objectA.PK_Id);

foreach:
  objectX.FK_ID = objectA.PK_ID;
  repoX.Add(objectX);

foreach:
  objectY.FK_ID = objectA.PK_ID;
  repoY.Add(objectY);

foreach:
  objectZ.FK_ID = objectA.PK_ID;
  repoZ.Add(objectZ);

  _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

Now I asked myself, should it not be enough or better to do all foreach.Add operations not on the repoXXX just instead
do the Add operation on the children collections?:

```
repoA.Update(objectA);
repoY.Delete(objectA.Id);

foreach:
  objectA.CollectionX.Add(objectX);
  objectA.CollectionY.Add(objectY);
  objectA.CollectionZ.Add(objectZ);

  _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

A sidenote:

The Delete operation on repoY could not be done inmemory as the objects_Y are not loaded into the context.

What do you think?

I tagged this question also with domain driven design maybe this scenario has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually approaching this from a DDD perspective, then it's concerning to me that you have repositories for all the child entities and not just for the aggregate root, `A`.  Obviously, every project is different, and DDD is a set of guidelines that usually make sense.  However, I would expect that `repoA` handles loading and persisting all four entities, unless X, Y, and Z have roles to play as aggregate roots.  `RepositoryA` could handle loading and persisting `X`, `Y`, and `Z` objects from various sources if they aren't all stored in one record, but I wouldn't expect separate repositories.

Aside from canonical DDD correctness, I encourage you to consider how these relationships work in your domain layer.  The `foreach` approach implies using setters, whereas the collection addition implies business objects establishing relationships in a way that can be expressed in the Ubiquitous Language.

I think your latter approach is more "correct", but I would alter it slightly:

```
repoA.Update(objectA);
repoY.Delete(objectA.Id);

foreach:
  objectA.addX(objectX);
  objectA.addY(objectY);
  objectA.addZ(objectZ);

  _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

Operations that alter child entities are typically exposed on the aggregate root itself, since it knows how to maintain the invariants it requires.

Hopefully that helps.  However, I don't know your entire situation.  It would help to understand a little more about what `AXYZ()` is doing.

Comment: The AXYZ() method has no own logic except that it is grouping repository calls within a business transaction. I agree with most of your comments. But one problem/concern I see. When I would follow strictly the DDD approach then my objectA should have a objectA.DeleteY(ObjectY). The CollectionOfObjectY is fetched via a FetchById method of my GenericRepository<T>. The below DeleteY method is then also called in a foreach like the addXXX methods. What do you think?